# Do I still get credit for views if I use shortened URLs?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, publicity-badges, short-links

If I press the `link` button under a question and then shorten the generated URL using http://bit.ly/, will traffic I generate still count as views for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortened URL works like a link so it sends you to the page. If it would have counted as a view as a normal URL, it will as a shortened URL.

Comment: can I earn the publistes badge if I press the link button on SO?

Comment: I would believe so. A shortened URL is just doing a HTTP Redirect (or it should be).